# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using console

Tags: java, console, noclassdeffounderror

I have a problem with the execution of programs by console. It always throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError but if i run the same application with netbeans it works perfectly.What can i do?

Comment: have you built your application?

Comment: Have you set your `CLASSPATH`? IDE does it for you but outside it's your responsibility.

Comment: you need to add the dependencies to the classpath e.g. java -classpath ".;c:\project\*" MyJavaProg

Answer (score 0):

You can add classpath in Java by providing option "-cp" or "-classpath" while running Java program.

set classpath there as shown below :

```
 Set CLASSPATH=.;/com/test/classes

 java -cp $CLASSPATH Test
```

By default Java CLASSPATH points to current directory denoted by "." and it will look for any class only in current directory.

Comment: the problem is that i didn't use any external class.

Comment: @alessio can you post the full stacktrace please?

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath is set differently i.e. jar(s) on the classpath in NetBeans are not on the classpath when you run the same code from the console.

A quick code snippet which outputs what is on your classpath:

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

for(URL url: urls){ System.out.println(url.getFile()); }
```

From the console, use the -cp option to add the necessary jars.